# mongodb how to find Multiple Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

in mongodb how can i find multiple documents at ones??

in my post method i have appoinments collection.when getting post data i want check they already in database using `hour_responce` and `date_responce` but how can i do with 2 documents.its working fine with only one docement.

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body[0])
   if(req.params.collectionName == 'appoinments'){
      req.collection.findOne({date_responce:req.body[0].date_responce,hour_responce:req.body[0].hour_responce}, function(e, result){
          if(result){
            console.log(result); console.log(e)
            res.send(500,{error:"You Already have a Task on this Time Period"})
          }
          else{
            req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send(results)

             })
          }
      })
  }
  else{
     req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send(results)
        })
  }

})
```

**---UPDATE----**

```
{ toArray: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  next: [Function],
  nextObject: [Function],
  setReadPreference: [Function],
  batchSize: [Function],
  count: [Function],
  stream: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  explain: [Function],
  isClosed: [Function],
  rewind: [Function],
  limit: [Function],
  skip: [Function],
  hint: [Function],
  maxTimeMS: [Function],
  sort: [Function],
  fields: [Function] }
```

Comment: Umm. Possibly the `.find()` method? `.findOne()` should be fairly self explanatory don't you think? You also might think to explain this a bit better as well.

Comment: ok.i have two documents `invoice`, `appoinments` but i want to check before posting `appoinments` it allready in the database using unique value `hour_responce` and `date_responce`.but `invoice` collection want to save without checking.how can i do this and `req.collection.findOne({hour_responce:req.body[0].hour_responce}, function(e, result){` using one condition to check this code fine but how can i do this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using findOne method of your collection.

You can try with : find() method, and then iterate on your resultset to make your comparisons

EDIT :

```
req.collection.find({}).toArray(function(e,result){

});
```

Comment: for(r in result){ if(result[r].attr===data){console.log('okay');}

Comment: and this code not working with find method.i tryied i update the question with error log

Comment: use toArray() method after your call to find() ... see my edit

Comment: can you show me correct way to do my conditions `find({date_responce:req.body[0].date_responce,hour_responce:req.body[0].hour_responce},`